# secure php contact form with htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])

Tags: php

I am very new to php and am trying to create a simple, secure and functioning contact form on a webpage. My form is as followed:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" >
<fieldset>

    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="col-md-1  text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <input id="fname" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="col-md-1  text-center"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o bigicon"></i></span>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="col-md-1  text-center"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o bigicon"></i></span>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your massage for us here. We will get back to you within 2 business days." rows="7"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

and I have the following php file (called mail.php) that I would like to execute when SEND button is pressed.

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "some.email@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");?>
```

Question is; if I have

```
action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"
```

how can I execute the php script in mail.php?

Comment: If you're trying to execute mail.php, have you tried clicking the submit button?

Comment: ARE YOU GETTING ANY SYNTEX ERROR? Use single quotes **['PHP_SELF'];**

Comment: @AmitThakur Double quotes are valid syntax for array keys.

Comment: Also, if you're looking for secure, you're currently vulnerable to header injection - take a look at http://www.damonkohler.com/2008/12/email-injection.html